# Laying out content with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am starting an application that will use HTML / CSS. While I'm fairly familiar with the two technologies, I am having problems creating my default layout. Basically, I want the following:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                             |
| This section will be as large as the content that it holds  |
|                                                             |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                             |
|                                                             |
| This section will take up the remaining available space.    |
| No matter what. If more space is required, scroll only this |
| content.                                                    |
|                                                             |
|                                                             |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                             |
| This section will be as large as the content that it holds  |
|                                                             |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
```

How do I use HTML / CSS to acomplish this?

Comment: [cssstickyfooter.com](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) is a good place to look; it will keep your third panel _at minimum_ at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Please also post what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/ratbum/TUytU/4/

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML5 and CSS, we will call the top section `<header>` and the bottom, `<footer>`, for semantic reference. We will also call the center section of your content `<article>`.

If you set both the `<header>` AND `<footer>` to `position: fixed;` only the center section or `<article>` will scroll.  Check out my result in the jsfiddle linked below. Easy peasy!

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/codesushi156/5wc25/4/